# ApplicationSettings across libraries

Tags: .net, application-settings

I'm trying to abstract out all database code into a separate library and then use that library in all my code. All database connections are done using typed TableAdapters that I create by dragging and dropping in datasets in VS2005, using a connection string from the appSettings.

The problem that I haven't been able to solve is that .Net doesn't propagate the libraries appSettings to the other project that's using it.

In short, I have a database layer library, MyProgram.DbLayer, which is used by other projects such as MyProgram.Client etc. When I had all the datasets in the .Client the connectionString was in MyProgram.Client.exe.config so that I could change it after build. When I moved it into the MyProgram.DbLayer that setting isn't avaliable to me after I build the binaries.

EDIT:
This seems to be a more general issue with ApplicationSettings.

What I noticed was that if I manually add a setting only used in a library it will be properly read. The only thing I need now is for the setting to be automatically included in the .config file as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppSettings/ConnectionStrings will always be read from the currently running app pool.

By this I mean:

If I have `A.exe` which has a class `DAL.cs`. DAL.cs reads a connection string from config, and it returns `"abc"` as expected.

I then move DAL.cs to its own project, and thus, its own assembly. I can still have it call the connection string from app.config, however, **I will need to "host" the assembly in a running application, and add the connection string to that applications app config**. So, I create a new app.config and specify the connection string `"xyz"` in it, when it runs, it runs as expected.

Now, if I change the reference in the `A.exe` project to use the new `DAL.dll`, what connection string do you think it will have? `"xyz"`? Nope! It will use the `"abc"` as it did before because that is still configured in the application configuration file for `A.exe`.

I know this works because I used shared DAL code across many Windows **and** Web applications.

If any of this is unclear, or does not help your problem, please let me know by commenting on this answer.

#### Update following comment from OP

By "host" I mean an application that is calling on the common code. This can be a Windows or a Web application, basically it is the application context.

You will need to create entries in the configuration files for each application that uses the common code. If I misunderstood your original question (entirely possible, it's been a long day!) and you wish to centralize the configuration as well, then you would need to:

- Create some form of centralised storage (be it XML, DB, whatever).
- Enhance your common code to have default values to enable it to connect to the centralised storage.
- From there, the code can then configure itself, based on the information in the configuration store.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Not sure I understand the "host" part. Should I manually add DAL.dll's app.config sections into A.exe's app.config?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, it sounds like you'll need

1.) A common application context for all data access calls

or

2.) A different way of accessing configuration settings

1: Wrap your data layer within a service that runs under a single context (IIS, Windows Service, etc)

2: Don't use the Configuration Management mechanism that you are supplied.  Instead use property files in a specific location.

Don't forget though that the configuration settings cascade from different levels.  For example...if you add a setting in machine.config, then every application running on that machine will use that setting unless it is replaced at a lower level...That may be a good way to setup a standardized setting within your configuration files.